# why is my for loop() not outputting as expected

Tags: for-loop

```
d
```

The above 'd' is a data frame which outputs the following table containing
14 obs and 2 vars.

```
NUMBER       DATE
1      20 2017-01-01
2      30 2017-01-02
3      40 2017-01-03
4      40 2017-01-04
5      50 2017-01-05
6      50 2017-01-06
7      60 2017-01-07
8      20 2017-01-08
9      30 2017-01-09
10     40 2017-01-10
11     40 2017-01-11
12     50 2017-01-12
13     50 2017-01-13
14     60 2017-01-14
```

After running the following code:

```
a<-c(0,7)

for(i in a){

 w <- subset(d, DATE >= as.Date("2017-01-01")+a & DATE <= as.Date("2017-01- 
07")+a )

print(w)
}
```

I get the following output. I was expecting the output to be two tables with the first dates 1st-7th and the second 8th-14. If i change the 'a' variable in the code to just '0' or just '7' it will run the dates as i'd expect (but obviously only 1 table each time i run the for loop).

```
NUMBER       DATE
1      20 2017-01-01
3      40 2017-01-03
5      50 2017-01-05
7      60 2017-01-07
8      20 2017-01-08
10     40 2017-01-10
12     50 2017-01-12
14     60 2017-01-14
   NUMBER       DATE
1      20 2017-01-01
3      40 2017-01-03
5      50 2017-01-05
7      60 2017-01-07
8      20 2017-01-08
10     40 2017-01-10
12     50 2017-01-12
14     60 2017-01-14
```

So how do i get the output to show table 1: 1st-7th dates and table 2: 8th-14th dates?

Answer (score 0):

I realise my error now. I was using 'a' instead of 'i' within the for loop.